# Postgresql error 53300 even though there are fewer connections than maximum allowed

Tags: asp.net, postgresql

I'm using `npgsql` on my ASP.NET application to connect to a postgres database. On trying to open a connection, I get the following error: `53300: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections`.

Now, the maximum number of connections is set to 100 (verified with `SHOW max_connections;`) and currently, there are only 6 connections that are active (as returned by `select count(*) from pg_stat_activity;`).

I have tried restarting postgres without any luck.

Why am I getting the 53300 error?

Comment: If you cannot connect, how and when are you doing `SHOW max_connections;` and `select count(*) from pg_stat_activity;`?

Comment: Turn on log_connections and log_disconnections.

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing your `max_connections` variable in *postgresql.conf* file and restart your PostgreSQL server.
Your application seem to open many connections while working.